# jquery for button click not working

Tags: jquery

This is my jquery code :

1. List item

   ```
   $(document).ready(function () {


       var VisibleDiv = $("hdnDivValue");
       var Task = $("DF_d-L_Mytaskdiv");
       var TaskReport = $("DF_d-L_Comptaskdiv");
       var LeaveReport = $("DF_d-L_LeaveReqdiv");

       var btnLeaveMang1 = $("btnLeaveMang");
       var btnMy_Task1 = $("btnMy_Task");
       var btn_TaskReport1 = $("btn_TaskReport");

       btn_TaskReport1.click(function () {
           VisibleDiv.val() == "DF_d - L_Mytaskdiv";

       });

       btnMy_Task1.click(function () {
           VisibleDiv.val() == "DF_d-L_Comptaskdiv";
       });

       btnMy_Task1.click(function () {
           VisibleDiv.val() == "DF_d-L_LeaveReqdiv";
       });



       if (VisibleDiv.val() == "DF_d-L_Comptaskdiv") {

           TaskReport.show();
           Task.hide();
           LeaveReport.hide();
       }

       else if (VisibleDiv.val() == "DF_d-L_Mytaskdiv") {
           TaskReport.hide();
           Task.show();
           LeaveReport.hide();

       }
       else if (VisibleDiv.val() == "DF_d-L_LeaveReqdiv") {
           TaskReport.hide();
           Task.hide();
           LeaveReport.show();
       }



   });
   ```

In my design i have three html controls and three div that contain grid and server controls

i written above code to display one div at  time on pageload and according to button click i have to show the respective grid.but my jquery code is not working any body have any idea..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to bind correctly for example as below

```
var VisibleDiv = $("#hdnDivValue");//if it is element id
var VisibleDiv = $(".hdnDivValue");//if it is class
```

Then you can use event handling

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this

```
VisibleDiv.val() == "DF_d-L_LeaveReqdiv";
```

Use correctly val function

```
VisibleDiv.val("DF_d-L_LeaveReqdiv");
```

Answer (score 0):

Simly assign value as

```
VisibleDiv = "DF_d - L_Mytaskdiv";
```

As VisibleDiv variable already contains HTML: DOM element.

So

```
VisibleDiv = "Your value";
```